# Config files for

Tags: c#, .net, config, workflow-foundation

I am working on some legacy code in .Net Framework 4.7.1 and trying to access app settings from **MyActivity.dll.config**.  Said dll is being referenced and utilized by a Microsoft Workflow Foundations xaml file.  When that code below is executed, it returns an empty string.

```
var string = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"]
```

I did some logging to a text file and verified it is coming back blank.  I also checked for the presence of said config file being in the same directory as **MyActivity.dll**.  Lastly, I checked and logged within the code the path of the assembly and it was in a weird place (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\7d28ecb5\9e49f345\assembly\dl3\1e60f07b\5ff4cf31_9738d801\MyActivity.dll).  For grins, I also placed a copy of the config file in there and nothing different happened.  Below is a snippet of the config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="SMTPServer" value="smtp.office365.com"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Anyone have any clue as to what may resolve this.  Much thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the name of your program and config file?

Comment: Edited my post for clarity.  Thanks!

Comment: You are running a DLL? How? What are you running. Web, Console?

Comment: If you are running an exe the name of the config should be `applicationname.exe.config`. If you are running web on IIS with .Net framework you would need a `web.config`. If you are running .Net Core on IIS you would need a `applicationsettings.json`. So you see I needs some context here.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post for clarity.  This dll is being referenced by a Microsoft Workflow Foundation xaml.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example i have created.
My application name is ConsolApp2.

I have added configuration in the app.config file

```
<configuration>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
</startup>  
<appSettings>
    <add key="SMTPServer" value="smtp.office365.com"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

After compile I got this in the ConsoleApp2.exe.config file

And for the getting this string you have to use
using System.Configuration;

and with the code below you will get the configuration string

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string SMTPserver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"];
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.  This Workflow was being used by a 3rd party web app and the keys needed to belong in the web.config file. Hat tip to **Paul Sinnema** for pointing me in the right direction!